# What word did the Romans use to describe a hot, dry, sandy desert?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, nature

Did the Romans during the classical era have a word for a dry, hot, desert? There is *desertum*, but that is more "wilderness" than explicitly desert in the sense we might think of today. Another possibility is *solitudo*, as used in [this quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(full)#ubi_solitudinem_faciunt_pacem_appellant) , although that seems to have similar meaning like *desertum* and not specifically a hot desert. Post classical Latin has *erema*, but is there an equivalent in classical Latin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to *desertum*, *solitudo* and *erema*, [Calonghi dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=isbn+8870110060) suggests two more choices.

The plural ***Deserta***:
[image: Deserta Apuliae (Seneca)]
(Virgil, Pliny, Seneca).

Also, ***Vastitas***, as alternative to *deserta*:
[image: Vastitas Lybiae - Deserta Lybiae]

Both here refer to geographic areas (*deserta Apuliae* and *vastitas Lybiae*) that may likely have been "proper deserts" a couple of millenniums ago.

Comment: Thanks @MattAllegro! Was _erema_ used in classical times? I can see that the others were, but it wasn't clear to me with that one.

Comment: @Adam I found no reference now but I will ask again. Open a follow-up question to attract attention on the _erema_ matter

Comment: @Adam Ifound a reference of Justinian using the word _erema_. This is pretty much all I can say and I really suggest you to open a new thread about this...better than in comments :)